# how to split an array into equal chunks?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've found a lot of answers to the question "how to split an array in multiple chunks", but I can't find a way to best repartition the array. For example,

```
let x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];

//#Source https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/fundamental/javascript-fundamental-exercise-265.php
const chunk = (arr, size) =>
Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, (v, i) =>
  arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size)
);

const n = 10;

console.log(chunk(x,n))
```

This function gives me two arrays: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and [11,12,13]`. But I would prefere n to be used as a "max" to obtain [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and [8,9,10,11,12,13]. This way I would have two arrays of the same size. If it is possible for the selected n, they should be of equal size, otherwise, two arrays with a nearly identical size.

Comment: Do you want always two chunks?

Comment: @Alex, no. He wants to partition an array over n "chunks" (just a subset of the initial array).

Comment: please add some examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I broke it down into 3 steps.

1. Compute `numChunks`, how many chunks you need? E.g. if you have an array of 103 elements and a max size of 10, then you'll need 11 chunks.
2. Compute `minChunkSize`, the size of the smaller chunks. E.g. in the above example, the first 7 chunks will have 10 elements, while the other 3 chunks will have 11 elements (7*10 + 3*11 = 103).
3. Compute `numSmallChunks`, how many small chunks you can have. E.g. 3 in the above example.

Then you just splice the `arr` accordingly.

```js
let chunk = (arr, maxSize) => {
    let numChunks = parseInt((arr.length - 1) / maxSize) + 1;
    let minChunkSize = parseInt(arr.length / numChunks);
    let numSmallChunks = numChunks * (minChunkSize + 1) - arr.length;

    arr = [...arr]; // avoid muckking the input
    let arrays = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numChunks; i++)
        if (i < numSmallChunks)
            arrays.push(arr.splice(0, minChunkSize));
        else
            arrays.push(arr.splice(0, minChunkSize + 1));

    return arrays;
};

let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
for (let i = 1; i < x.length; i++)
  console.log(i, JSON.stringify(chunk(x, i), null, ''));
```

Note, the other answers result in an unbalanced; e.g. they produce arrays of sizes 4, 4, 4, & 1 when `n` is 4. Whereas my approach produces arrays of sizes 3, 3, 3, & 4. I guess it's up to the situation which you need, but this is how I interpret the question's "equal chunks".

Comment: Both of the answers are good. This is a memory management question in OS, is it not?

Comment: I imagine it could have numerous applications. E.g. dividing tasks for a fixed number of workers, load balancing a fixed number of requests, etc.

Comment: I think it would be better if the bigger chunks were at the beginning (Guess that's just opinion based)

Comment: That's possible if you replace the if predicate with `i >= numChunks - numSmallChunks` or something equivalent.

Comment: Wow! That is exactly what I wanted to do, thank you! I have to make an online scientist experiment and it contains many trials. I wanted to split these trials in blocks to allow my participants to take some breaks. That's why I wanted many blocks with the same number of trials when possible and with the best repartition when it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you need `n` to be max, Then calculate `size` as below.

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

const chunk = (arr, max) => {
  const size = Math.min(max, Math.ceil(arr.length / 2));
  return Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, (v, i) =>
    arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size)
  );
};

const n = 10;

console.log(chunk(x, n));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slice with a variable size.

```
 1  2  3  4  5    5
 6  7  8  9 10    5
11 12 13 14       4
15 16 17 18       4
```

```js
const
    chunk = (array, max) => {
        let
            length = Math.ceil(array.length / max),
            size = Math.ceil(array.length / length);

        return Array.from(
            { length },
            (_, i) => (
                array.length === size * length - length + i && size--,
                array.slice(size * i, size * (i + 1))
            )
        );
    }

console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], 5).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```